# Setting innerHTML doesn't set it

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How is this possible?

```
title.innerHTML = 'blah';
alert(title+' : '+title.innerHTML+' : '+title.outerHTML);
```

Gives me an alert stating:

```
[object HTMLHeadingElement] : undefined : undefined
```

In Chrome v28. How?

Comment: What is `title`?  Please show us the code that sets that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd previously assigned title to the 'title' attribute of an Element.

```
function createContent() {
    var content = document.createElement('div');
    var title = document.createElement('h1');
    content.title = title;
    return content;
}

var content = createContent();
title = content.title;
title.innerHTML = 'blah';
alert(title+' : '+title.innerHTML+' : '+title.outerHTML);
```

Alerts:

```
[object HTMLHeadingElement] : undefined : undefined
```

Assuming I'm using undefined behaviour (misusing title attribute) or a bug.

Comment: To clarify, content.title casts to string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the element into the DOM first, then you will be able to access those properties.

Complete your `createContent` function with `appendChild` to insert the created content in the DOM and then returning that node.